# How do i create a floating button without using the material design library

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-button

I am trying to draw a **floating button(kinda)** as soon as the **Android soft keypad** comes up and make it to disappear when keypad vanishes. So its like trying to get a button along with the keypad.. So the button must accompany the keypad.

Comment: You can use CardView. 56dp width/height, 28 radius.

Comment: well i m asking without the card view